# Encryption using public key from eth_getEncryptionPublicKey metamask function

Tags: web3js, metamask, javascript, web3.py, encryption

I'm trying to encrypt data/files before uploading them to IPFS and I want to do this using metamask provided public and private keys. For this, I have tried using [eth_getEncryptionPublicKey](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/rpc-api.html#eth-getencryptionpublickey) but this gives me a public key of length 48 characters which is similar to `ZvpXeyKc1iJbidfr0TL7BAmyofkCdaPUvVvcDI/FEWc=` also I'm using vanilla js so can't find a way to use `eth-sig-util`

Can someone suggest some algorithm that supports this public key length or help me use eth-sig-util into js

Answer (score 2):

I think this [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethdev/comments/r7xa8i/using_metamask_to_encrypt_message_offchain/) might help :)